# Subdomain Index file referencing error

Tags: php

When I visit my domain "domain.com" it loads up index.php, however when I visit subdomain.domain.com it doesn't load up the index.php. Typing in subdomain.domain.com/index.php it works just fine, if I don't then the .htaccess redirects me to the 404 ErrorDocument.

The DNS is configured correctly, but this one little thing is annoying me.

Hosting provider: Hostgator.com

Comment: What _do_ you see when you visit subdomain.domain.com? What page is the server configured to serve as the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably isnt a directoryindex set up in your subdomains .htaccess. http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/

Comment: I made a DirectoryIndex in that folder before and to no avail, eurgh must of been a temp glitch. Thanks however. Feel really stupid now. :]